# Why is my shutdown time so long?

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, shutdown

Running windows XP SP2 I can be waiting for up to 5 minutes after hitting the shut-down button until the machine actually switches off.

I have tried killing an non essential services/application before I shut down to see if that makes a difference but it doesn't appear to.

Can anyone suggest why the machine takes so long to close down and possible solutions (NOTE: To actually boot up the computer is extremely quick and I don't have many application/services starting up either)

Comment: check the event log.

Comment: There is nothing in the event log for the time of shutdown that has warnings or errors

Comment: When did this start btw?

Comment: I have noticed it getting gradually slower over the course of the last 2 months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a way to fasten the shutdown by cutting the time for killing services (taken from [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/01/03/reduce-windows-xp-shutdown-time/)):

> The first two settings can be found in
>   the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`. They are called
>   **HungAppTimeout** and
>   **WaitToKillAppTimeout**. You should also
>   set the key **AutoEndTasks** to 1 if it is
>   not set to this value already.
>
> The timeout settings for Services can
>   be found in the Registry key
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control`
>   and is called
>   **WaitToKillServiceTimeout**. The value is
>   entered in miliseconds which means
>   that the value 2000 should be entered
>   if you want to set this to 2 seconds
>   each.

Answer (score 1):

Try going through device manager through your USB section and disable the setting to allow Windows to turn off the device to save power.  This can sometimes cause a shutdown to hang.  I had a laptop in last week that had the hanging shutdown and this corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a member of a domain?  Roaming profiles?